# Conver HTML to image and Reduce Image quality

Tags: c#, html, printing, converters

i need to convert a html file to image and print It in c#, but when i convert file with NRECO, nitro, Aspose, coreHtmlToImage and ... , quality of image is low and resolation in not OK ...

I Used Nreco, Aspose,EoBrowser,HtmlRender and many other DLL to convert but all of them reduce the image quality

Comment: How you tried ImageGenerator.CustomArgs = "--quality 100" in NRECO?

Comment: Yes, but the resualt is not OK

Comment: We request you please create a topic in official Aspose.HTML support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/html) where you can share your sample HTML along with the sample code snippet that you are using. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. Please note that official support forum is the right place to report and discuss such issues and you can track the resolution progress there as well. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.